# How do I change a data source in a data grid view using a combo box in vb.net?

Tags: sql, vb.net, winforms, datagridview, combobox

I have combo box on my windows form with several items in it. Ideally I would like to be able to change the data source, which is several different SQL Server tables, in the data grid view depending on what item is selected in the combo box.

Also, If there is a way to display a sql query in a data grid view that would be helpful as well.

Thanks.

```
 Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    If ComboBox1.Text.Equals("DATA") Then
        MessageBox.Show("DATA")
        'DataSource = "Data Source=CSGFS01;Database=_CHRIS;Table=WorkOrders;Trusted_Connection=True;"
        DataSource = "DATA"
    End If

    If ComboBox1.Text.Equals("DESIGN") Then
        MessageBox.Show("DESIGN")
        DataSource = "DESIGN"
    End If

    If ComboBox1.Text.Equals("INKJET") Then
        MessageBox.Show("INKJET")
        DataSource = "INKJET"
    End If

    If ComboBox1.Text.Equals("PRINT") Then
        MessageBox.Show("PRINT")
        DataSource = "PRINT"
    End If

    If ComboBox1.Text.Equals("QC") Then
        MessageBox.Show("QC")
        DataSource = "QC"
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub TabPage1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TabPage1.Click
    Me.Width = -20
    Me.Height = -20
End Sub


Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick_1(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick
    Dim cmd As OleDb.OleDbCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM WorkOrders WHERE STATUS IS 'DATA'")
    Me.WorkOrdersTableAdapter.Fill(Me._CHRISDataSet.WorkOrders)

End Sub
```

Comment: You really need to do the research yourself.  Then when you get stuck in the code post a relevant question with [mcve].  Please study [Ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: There's my code, Plutonix.